# How to access data related to individual particles?

Tags: modifiers, particles, drivers

I would like to create simple drivers to manipulate ***individual*** data points for things like *Particles* and *Array Modifiers*.

Just as an example, when I create a particle system, if I create a driver for the ***Size*** parameter, it changes the size of all the particles simultaneously (as it should).  But I would instead like to access the size for ***each individual particle***.

For something like an array modifier, I would like to access the data paths ***for each instance***.  For example, add a randomized driver to create different iterations of the original mesh.

Are either of these examples possible?

Comment: While we can read particle data, we can't alter it. See my response [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/81666/935). I expect animation nodes will be your solution.

Comment: @sambler - Thanks.  Are you saying that animation nodes could accomplish the same thing?  For example, with particles, I want to have the particles generate get larger over time... but all the particles should keep their size throughout the simulation.

Comment: Animation nodes can duplicate an object and place it at the location of each particle, you can then calculate the size and rotation of each instance which can include the frame number in the calculation. Actually [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87120/935) should get you started.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Sambler said, Animation Nodes is your best option. Here are some examples:

Controlling the size of individual particles based on time (They get bigger as time passes):

[image: Node Tree 1]

Controlling the rotation of individual particles based on a random vector.

[image: Node Tree 2]

Wiggling the size of instances cube:

[image: Node Tree 3]

Comment: +1 - Quick question: In the first example, just looking at one individual particle, will the particle keep the same size throughout the simulation?  Never used animation nodes before, but it looks like each particle would continue to scale with animation length.

Comment: @bertmoog That is true, current node tree will make it keep scaling. But you can just make it fixed. Tell me exactly what you need and I will provide an example.