# Level of Detail of Particles System?

Tags: particles, drivers

[image]

First, the GIF above is a 60-frame sequence with a 1080x1920 size that uses a freestyle to render the outline.

This scene is a lot of polygon counts using the full shot model because the characters fly away from the camera closer to the sky.

After all, my PC output only 60 frames at the end of four days and three nights full-time rendering.

I knew that the freestyle was sensitive to the polygon count, but I wanted to be able to do this,

so I looked up LOD and tried the test.

[image]

Prepared three levels of models.

[image]

I set the render toggle to turn off and on depending on the distance between the camera and the object using the driver.

[image]

However, the particle is reflected only by the change of the original object whether it can not be operated as an individual object or not.

Can particles emitted from an emitter have their own LOD?

Or, if there is another good way to create a scene like the top GIF, let me know please.

I will look forward to your teachings.

Thanks for reading...

Comment: Looks like a job for animation nodes. The solution should be similar to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87123/935).

Comment: Oh, the animation nodes. i'll look at it. Thanks.